# How to display free shipping total on header.tpl in opencart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart

Im new to coding. I want to display free shipping total in home page header.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to controller file header.php

```
if ($this->config->get('free_total')) {
 $data['free_total'] = $this->config->get('free_total');
} else {
 $data['free_total'] = false;
}
```

after go to headet.tpl and put where you need

```
<?php echo $free_total; ?>
```